# In-app purchases trouble with SwiftyStoreKit and AppStore Connect moderator

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, swiftystorekit

I'm newbie with in-app purchases and SwiftyStoreKit.

I made an in-app purchases in my app and sent it for moderation.

My application moderator rejected and wrote the reason:

> We found that your in-app purchase products exhibited one or more bugs
> when reviewed on iPhone and iPad running iOS 14.1 on Wi-Fi.
>
> Specifically, your app’s In-App Purchases do not show the app’s price.
> Also, upon further review, we found that your app does not allow users
> to purchase the In-App Purchases.
>
> Next Steps
>
> When validating receipts on your server, your server needs to be able
> to handle a production-signed app getting its receipts from Apple’s
> test environment. The recommended approach is for your production
> server to always validate receipts against the production App Store
> first. If validation fails with the error code "Sandbox receipt used
> in production," you should validate against the test environment
> instead.

The price was not displayed probably because the application received the answer code: "skerrordomain code=0" or something like that. Or because the Apple server returned 0 products.

That is, when ViewController starts, app request the price of the products from the Apple server and then write it down to the buttons.

I don't know exactly what the problem is, because on my local device purchases work with a Sandbox user. In Simulator I get an error: "skerrordomain code=0".

Here is a code sample:

```
enum RegisteredPurchase: String {
    case item1 = "com.app.appname.item1"
    case item2 = "com.app.appname.item2"
    case item3 = "com.app.appname.item3"
}

purchases: [RegisteredPurchase]

var productList: Set<String> = []
for purchase in purchases {
    productList.insert(purchase.rawValue)
}
SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo(productList) { result in
    var products: Dictionary<RegisteredPurchase, String> = [:]
    for product in result.retrievedProducts {
        products[RegisteredPurchase(rawValue: product.productIdentifier)!] = product.localizedPrice
    }
    if (result.error == nil) {
        self.setupPrice(products)
    }
    
}
```

In the result I get retrievedProducts. On the local device all 3 products come, in Simulator I get 0 and the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by removing all products and creating new ones.